# How to prevent CKFinder renaming files with multiple extensions?

Tags: php, ckfinder

When I upload files with multiple extensions using CKFinder (with PHP), it renames them, replacing the dots with underscores for all but the last one. For example it will rename `file.1.1.jpg` to `file_1_1.jpg`. Setting the [`CheckDoubleExtension`](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/PHP/Configuration/Security/Double_file_extensions) config property to `false` prevents the rename but I don't see why it's being applied because `1` is not a disallowed char and does not appear in my `deniedExtensions` list for the resource type I'm uploading. Also I don't really want to disable it because I'd like the protection it adds - but it's not much use if it's broken. However I can't find any other config items that are related to this.

How can I prevent CKFinder renaming these files without losing this protection?

Answer (score 0):

If `allowedExtensions` is defined then it has higher priority than `deniedExtensions`. If `1` is not on the list of allowed extensions, it has the same meaning for CKFinder as `exe` or `php`.

> How can I prevent CKFinder renaming these files without losing this protection?

Right now in CKFinder 2.x the only way to achieve what you need is to extend the list of allowed extensions.

If you fill a [feature request](https://github.com/ckfinder/ckfinder) and there will be a significant demand for such feature, we may provide some way to define a callback in which you could sanitize the file name using your own rules.